# Best practice Mac Admin to wipe returned Mac

Tags: mac-osx

The issue we have is getting laptops back and needing to wipe them but the person is no longer contactable and they have not shared the password and they have left iCloud logged in.

I tried adding an admin account to the devices but they did not show up in recovery mode. I later found out that is due to the disk being encrypted by the user.

I have seen that mdm solutions will allow us to wipe but we don't need any other MDM services. So it seems silly to pay 10 a month per person so when they leave if they don't share their password we can wipe.

We are a small org of 30 odd people.

I can put what ever is needed on the machine before we hand them out.

What is the best none mdm solution that will make it easy to wipe after a person leaves?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/business/essentials/ is $3/month/user for your use case.

Comment: That is half my question. Is the only solution a payed solution? The only thing I need it to be able to wipe a device every few months. None of the other services are needed.